# Asynchronous socket client design

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

ALL,

Have the following problem.
First, here is my code:

```
class InternetConnector
{
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent( false );
    public static ManualResetEvent processingDone = new ManualResetEvent( false );
    public static ConcurrentQueue<string> messages = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    public static bool Connected;

    public bool ReceiveMessage(Action<Socket> successHandler, Action<Exception> errorHandler)
    {
        bool receive = false;
        ClientStateObject obj = new ClientStateObject();
        obj.server = client;
        var connectionData = new ConnectionData
        {
            ErrorHandler = errorHandler,
            SuccessHandler = successHandler,
            Socket = client,
            clientObj = obj
        };
        if (Connected)
        {
            client.BeginReceive(connectionData.clientObj.buffer, 0, ClientStateObject.bufSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), connectionData);
            receive = true;
            receiveDone.WaitOne();
        }
        return receive;
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ConnectionData connectionData = new ConnectionData();
        bool complete = false;
        try
        {
            connectionData = (ConnectionData)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = connectionData.Socket;
            int num = client.EndReceive(ar);
            {
                connectionData.clientObj.stringBuffer.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(connectionData.clientObj.buffer, 0, num));
                string response = connectionData.clientObj.stringBuffer.ToString();
                if (response.EndsWith("&"))
                    complete = true;
                string[] msgs = response.Split('&');
                int j = 0;
                if (!complete)
                    j++;
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.Count() - j; i++)
                {
                    string sts = msgs[i];
                    if (i == 0 && receivingMessage != String.Empty)
                    {
                        sts = receivingMessage + sts;
                        messages.Enqueue(sts + "&" );
                        receivingMessage = String.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                        messages.Enqueue(sts + "&");
                }
                if (!complete)
                    receivingMessage += msgs[msgs.Count() - 1];
                else
                    receivingMessage = String.Empty;
                receiveDone.Set();
                if (connectionData.SuccessHandler != null)
                {
                    connectionData.SuccessHandler(client);
                    processingDone.WaitOne();
                    client.BeginReceive(connectionData.clientObj.buffer, 0, ClientStateObject.bufSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), connectionData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (connectionData.ErrorHandler != null)
                connectionData.ErrorHandler(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the success handler:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void AsyncSuccessHandler(Socket socket)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action( () => AsyncSuccessHandler( socket ) ));
            return;
        }
        if (InternetConnector.messages.Count() == 0)
        {
            status.Text = "Signals Receiver: Connected";
            status.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            startStop.Text = "Stop";
            isRunning = true;
            create.Enabled = true;
            SetGUIColorsAndValues();
            client.SendMessageToConnector("First Signal Pass4&");
            client.ReceiveMessage(AsyncSuccessHandler, AsyncErrorHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            SetGUIColorsAndValues();
            GUIChangeOnConnection();
            InternetConnector.processingDone.Set();
        }
    }

    private void GUIChangeOnConnection()
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < InternetConnector.messages.Count; i++ )
        {
            string message;
            InternetConnector.messages.TryDequeu( out message );
            // process message
        }
    }
}
```

Problem:
I need to continuosly read the data from the server and display them in the GUI. I also need the GUI to be responsive to i.e. button clicks.
I also need to start n read iteration when n-1 read iteration has been finished processing and the concurrentqueue object in my code is empty.

However going thru the code in debugger I can see that BeginReceive() call in the reading callback does not wait till the end of success handler and the queue is not empty.

What am I missing? Is there a better way to achieve this?

I am also aware of SignalR library but at this pont I don't want to use any 3rd party library.

Any help in this matter appreciated.

Thank you.

[EDIT]

Do I understand Amit's reply correctly:

```
class InternetConnector
{
    private static ManualResetEvent processingDone = new ManualResetEvent( false );

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ConnectionData connectionData = new ConnectionData();
        bool complete = false;
        try
        {
            connectionData = (ConnectionData)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = connectionData.Socket;
            int num = client.EndReceive(ar);
            {
                connectionData.clientObj.stringBuffer.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(connectionData.clientObj.buffer, 0, num));
                string response = connectionData.clientObj.stringBuffer.ToString();
                if (response.EndsWith("&"))
                    complete = true;
                string[] msgs = response.Split('&');
                int j = 0;
                if (!complete)
                    j++;
                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.Count() - j; i++)
                {
                    string sts = msgs[i];
                    if (i == 0 && receivingMessage != String.Empty)
                    {
                        sts = receivingMessage + sts;
                        messages.Enqueue(sts + "&" );
                        receivingMessage = String.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                        messages.Enqueue(sts + "&");
                }
                if (!complete)
                    receivingMessage += msgs[msgs.Count() - 1];
                else
                    receivingMessage = String.Empty;
                receiveDone.Set();
                if (connectionData.SuccessHandler != null)
                {
                    processingDone.WaitOne();
                    connectionData.SuccessHandler(client);
                    processingDone.Set();
                    client.BeginReceive(connectionData.clientObj.buffer, 0, ClientStateObject.bufSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), connectionData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (connectionData.ErrorHandler != null)
                connectionData.ErrorHandler(e);
        }
    }
}
```

?

[/EDIT]
[EDIT 2]
Please see updated code.
When I set a breakpoint at the very end of the GUIChangeOnConnection() - line with the "}" - I see that the queue does have some items.
I will try to change ManualResetEvent, in the meantime.
[/EDIT 2]

Comment: It's not clear what's calling AsyncSuccessHandler to start with - so what thread it will start on. The loop at the end looks suspicious though.

Comment: Can you improve code formatting as it is very hard to read otherwise? I tried to edit but SO is not allowing me to do it as it is a trivial edit.

Comment: @JonSkeet, AsyncSuccessHandler is a function to call in case the socket operation is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood the problem correctly, you are referring to a problem at the following point of code:

```
if (connectionData.SuccessHandler != null)
{
    connectionData.SuccessHandler(client);
    client.BeginReceive(connectionData.clientObj.buffer, 0, ClientStateObject.bufSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), connectionData);
}
```

If your intention is that you hit server only when you have finished processing previous data then the `SuccessHandler` must be blocking (as is obvious from your problem statement as well).

Now take a look at the following lines in your `SuccessHandler`

```
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    BeginInvoke(new Action( () => AsyncSuccessHandler( socket ) ));
    return;
}
```

The above code defers the execution of your `SuccessHandler` so that the UI remains responsive. Or in other words, your `SuccessHandler` is not blocking.

Since you are updating GUI from the `SuccessHandler`, it is also important to run it from UI thread (which it is correctly doing right now).

So in order to make the `SuccessHandler` blocking, you can make the following code itself run on UI thread using `InvokeRequired` mechanism

```
if (connectionData.SuccessHandler != null)
{
    connectionData.SuccessHandler(client);
    client.BeginReceive(connectionData.clientObj.buffer, 0, ClientStateObject.bufSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), connectionData);
}
```

Since `client.BeginReceive` is async it will not block the UI thread and you anyway wanted to run `SuccessHandler` on UI thread..

If you don't have access to the Form in `ReceiveCallback`, you can use a waithandle to block call to `client.BeginReceive` till `SuccessHandler` has finished.

```
private static AutoResetEvent _processingDone = new AutoResetEvent( false );
//Introduce an internal property ProcessingDone to access _processingDone 
//This should be in a class which you can access both from 'Form1' and the class containing ReceiveCallBack

//In ReceiveCallBack
if (connectionData.SuccessHandler != null)
{
    connectionData.SuccessHandler(client);
    ProcessingDone.WaitOne();
    client.BeginReceive(connectionData.clientObj.buffer, 0, ClientStateObject.bufSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), connectionData);
}
```

ProcessingDone.Set() must be done from within `SuccessHandler` at a point where you can determine that `SuccessHandler` has finished and `client.BeginReceive` needs to be invoked.
This is internal to your logic. From the code you have shared, it is difficult to pin point the place where you need to put ProcessingDone.Set().

Comment: you understood correctly. Can you give me the proper C# syntax?

Comment: That will depend on whether 'ReceiveCallback' has access to the Form which contains AsyncSuccessHandler method...

Comment: No access. Why should it? It just a callback which should finish reading the socket. Remember, GUI runs on a different thread...

Comment: Yes, they run on different thread and that was my point. In order to block client.BeginReceive till you are done with SuccessHandler, you can simply make them both run on GUI thread. Currently you are running only SuccessHandler on GUI thread. If you don't have access to the Form in ReceiveCallback (and this fact is not very obvious from whatever little code you have shared) you can then easily block the receiveCallback till SuccessHandler is finished by using a waithandle just like receiveDone.

Comment: You mean something like this: "private static ManualResetEvent processingDone = new ManualResetEvent( false ); if( connectionData.SuccessHandler != null ) { processingDone.WaitOne(); connectionData.SuccessHandler( client ); processingDone.Set(); client.BeginReceive(); }". Thank you.

Comment: Amit, I made the change as you suggested. And now for some reason I see that the ConcurrentQueue object is growing up in size. I made a breakpoint in my success handler at the very end and when it hit the size of the queue is huge: ~10-11 thousand messages. It is not suppose to happen. Please refer to the modified code above. I got rid of the while loop and insert the processDone.Set() call. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. The loop looks like this: "for( int i = 0; i < InternetConnector.messages.Count; i++ ) { string message; InternetConnector.messages.TryDequeu( out message ); // message processing }" This loop is inside "GUIChangeOnConnection();"

Comment: This is because you are using ManualResetEvent. You need to reset 'processingDone' before invoking your successHandler so that receiveCallback can be blocked. However, it is better to use AutoResetEvent to avoid resetting it manually. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Amit, Never mind that. Sorry for the noise and apologies for wasting you time. I changed for() loop to while() loop and found that there is a bug in my code. Now everything works fine. Sorry once again and thank you for the help.

Comment: @Igor No Issues. I am happy that I could be of some help.